# Extract data from file with awk in bash script and store

Tags: bash, awk

I am new here and also a starter on programming so please handel me with care .

```
Filename = Datafile.tmp
```

I get a log file with 1 line of data like this (comma seperated)

```
24092014,17:21,357.7,5.1,49.96,228.6,7.9,1757.5,3378200.0,28.2,20680.0,846.0,1800.0,2
```

Maby i must explain shomething. I have a script writing in BASH that read out the data from the inverter by inside routine. I want to change that script so it read data out of the data file like above. The script is verry long but a place only the reading part of it.
So i think i can del all the reading port routines and just focus on the

convert data from array into readable data in my case from file.
and at the bottum storing variables to working file

```
#Ask data from inverter 
get_data() {
printf $GetDataCMD > $PORT
dd if=$PORT of=$OUT bs=1 count=$dataLengthTotal & 
PID=$!
sleep 3
if [ -d /proc/$PID ]
 then
  rcvd="no"
  kill $PID
 else
  rcvd="yes"
fi
}

#Put received data in array and check for errors
receive_data() {
(( dataLengthTotal = $ANS_OFFSET+$dataLengthOutput+1 ))
retry_counter=$RETRY
while (( retry_counter )); do
get_data < $PORT 2>/dev/null
if [ $rcvd = "yes" ]; then

  data=(`od -b -v $OUT | sed -e 's/^[0-9]*//g' | sed -e 's/[ ]\([0-9]\)/ 0\1/g'`)

  if [ ${#data[@]} -ne $dataLengthTotal ]; then
    rcvd="nochk"
    echo -e `date -R`":  Wrong amount of data received\r" >> $LOG
    init_comport
    (( retry_counter -= 1 ))
  else
    # Check CRC
    sumstr="${data[@]:$ANS_OFFSET:$dataLengthOutput}"
    let sum=${sumstr// /+}
    if ((sum%256 == data[9+$dataLengthOutput])); then
       rcvd="chk"
       retry_counter=0
    else
       rcvd="nochk"
       echo -e `date -R`":  Checksum error in received data\r" >> $LOG
       init_comport
       (( retry_counter -= 1 ))
    fi
  fi
else
  init_comport
  (( retry_counter -= 1 ))
fi
done
}

#convert data from array into readable data
get_current_data() {
dataLengthOutput=30
GetDataCMD=$GetCurrentDataCMD
receive_data
if [ $rcvd = "chk" ]; then
#errorbits
(( errbits = data[9+7] * 256 + data[9+6] ))
#Voltage Solarpanels (Usol)
(( Usol = data[9+9] * 256 + data[9+8] ))
#Current Solarpanels (Isol)
(( Isol = data[9+11] * 256 + data[9+10] ))
#AC Frequency (Fnet)
(( Fnet = data[9+13] * 256 + data[9+12] ))
#AC Voltage (Unet)
(( Unet = data[9+15] * 256 + data[9+14] ))
#AC Current (Inet)
(( Inet = data[9+17] * 256 + data[9+16] ))
#AC Power (Pnet)
(( Pnet = data[9+19] * 256 + data[9+18] ))
#Total delivered (Etot)
(( Etot = data[9+22] * 65536 + data[9+21] * 256 + data[9+20] + WtotOffset ))
#Temp Inverter (Tinv)
(( Tinv = data[9+23] ))
#Total runtime (Htot)
(( Htot = data[9+26] * 65536 + data[9+25] * 256 + data[9+24] + HtotOffset ))
#Total CO2 (Ctot)
(( Ctot = Etot * $CO2perc / 100 ))
fi
}

#check, convert and write error messages
convert_errorbits() {
ErrorStr="Systeem_OK"
if (( errbits )); then
if (( errbits & 0x01 )); then
  ErrorStr="Usolar too high (`print_float $Usol 1` V). ${ErrorStr}"
fi
if (( errbits & 0x02 )); then
  ErrorStr="Usolar too low (`print_float $Usol 1` V). ${ErrorStr}"
fi
if (( errbits & 0x04 )); then
  ErrorStr="No mains detected. ${ErrorStr}"
fi
if (( errbits & 0x08 )); then
  ErrorStr="Uac too high (${Unet} V). ${ErrorStr}"
fi
if (( errbits & 0x10 )); then
  ErrorStr="Uac too low (${Unet} V). ${ErrorStr}"
fi
if (( errbits & 0x20 )); then
  ErrorStr="FreqAC too high (`print_float $Fnet 2` Hz). ${ErrorStr}"
fi
if (( errbits & 0x40 )); then
  ErrorStr="FreqAC too low (`print_float $Fnet 2` Hz). ${ErrorStr}"
fi
if (( errbits & 0x80 )); then
  ErrorStr="Temperature error (${Tinv}ºC). ${ErrorStr}"
fi
if (( errbits & 0x100 )); then
  ErrorStr="Hardware error. ${ErrorStr}"
fi
if (( errbits & 0x200 )); then
  ErrorStr="Starting. ${ErrorStr}"
fi
if (( errbits & 0x400 )); then
  ErrorStr="Max output (${Pnet} W). ${ErrorStr}"
fi
if (( errbits & 0x800 )); then
  ErrorStr="I max (`print_float $Isol 2` A). ${ErrorStr}"
fi
echo -e `date -R`":   Error message: $ErrorStr\r" >> $LOG
fi
}

#Get current day output
get_current_day() {
dataLengthOutput=8
(( daynr = 0 ))
(( crc = $GetDailyDataCRC+$daynr ))
GetDataCMD=$GetDailyDataCMD1\\x`printf "%02X" $1 $daynr`$GetDailyDataCMD2\\x`printf    "%02X" $1 $crc`
receive_data
if [ $rcvd = "chk" ]; then
# Profit [kWH]
(( Etoday = data[9+7] * 256 + data[9+6] ))
# Runtime [h:mm]
(( Htoday = data[9+5] * 5 ))
# CO2
(( CO2 = Etoday * $CO2perc / 100 ))
fi
}



# Main Program
main(){
#set time variables
MTIME=`date +%M`
HTIME=`date +%H`

# Configure serial port
init_comport

#Store file contains data needed for calculating totals etc
#Internally an array is used, values are:
#0=Active flag
#1=WtotAct
#2=HtotAct
#3=WtotLog
#4=HtotLog
#fill array
store=(`cat $STORE`)

get_current_data

if [ $rcvd = "chk" ]; then
if (( ! store[0] )); then
  echo -e `date -R`":   Waking up; Inverter started.\r" >> $LOG
  store[0]=1
  if (( USE_30DAYS )); then
    get_last_30_days
  fi
  if [ ! -f $PVDIARYCSV ]
  then
    create_pvdiary
  fi
  if (( USE_EMAIL )) && (( USE_EMAwake )); then
    email_send "Bericht van uw zonnepanelen : ontwaken." "I'm awake now !\n\nUw Mastervolt Omvormer\n"
  fi
fi

# Remember 'old-values' for calculating PVDiary inputs
(( store[5] = store[1] ))
(( store[6] = 0 ))

# Put total values into array for calculating daily profit
store[1]=$Etot
store[2]=$Htot

convert_errorbits
get_current_day
create_actual_page
rrd_update
fill_pvdiary
fill_sql
pvoutput_live_update
fi

#Write message before sleep
if [ $rcvd = "no" ] && (( ! retry_counter )) && (( store[0] )); then
echo -e `date -R`":   No reaction from Inverter; entering sleep\r" >> $LOG
create_offline_page
store[0]=0
fi 

#Write 0-values in PVDiary-file
if [ $rcvd = "no" ] && (( ! retry_counter )) ; then
(( store[5] = store[1] ))
(( store[6] = 0 ))
fill_pvdiary
(( store[5] = store[1] ))
(( store[6] = 0 ))  
fill_sql    
(( store[5] = 0 ))
fi 

#Run timebased scripts (internal cron)
if [ $HTIME = 23 ] && [ $MTIME = 00 ]; then
fill_csv
fi  
if [ $MTIME = 00 ] && (( USE_RRD )); then
graph
fi
if [ $MTIME = 00 ] && (( store[0] )) && (( USE_EMAIL )) && (( USE_EMAhour )); then
email_send_actual "Bericht van uw zonnepanelen : productie tot nu toe."
fi

#storing variables to working file
echo ${store[0]} ${store[1]} ${store[2]} ${store[3]} ${store[4]} ${store[5]}${store[6]}> $STORE 
}

#What to do ?
case $1 in
"help"   ) help;;
"create" ) create;;
"draw"   ) graph;;
*        ) main;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F, '{print "Today = " $1 "\nTime = " $2 "\nHertz = " $5}' file
Today = 24092014
Time = 17:21
Hertz = 49.96
```

Comment: Thanks this a understand this. You use the print command give it a name and get the first out of the file etc etc. Can i put it direct into a variable or string ? like $Today and $Time etc so i can ude it all over the bash script ?

Comment: Yes but that'd almost certainly be the wrong approach. Unless you're manipulating files and processes, the right approach is to just write your whole script in awk. Post a new question describing your larger problem with sample input and expected output so we can help you with that.

Comment: I change my script maby you have a suggestion?